# why jdk says inputStream .available cant block ,but when i use in socket program ,it blocks

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

follows my code:

```
if (is != null) {
    while (is.available() == 0) {

    }
    firstDataPackageEnd = System.currentTimeMillis();
    int count = 0;
    String sdf = null;
    int length = 0;
    int acceptLenth = 0;
    Boolean firstRead = false;
    int headEnd = 0;

    while ((count = is.available()) > 0
            || (this.transferKind == TRANSFER_END_SPECIAL_LENGTH ? length < acceptLenth
                    : headEnd < 2)) {
    /*  System.out.println("允许通过的:" + acceptLenth);
        System.out.println("已经有:" + length);
        System.out.println("有结尾标志:" + headEnd);
    */  length = length + count;
        byte[] b = new byte[count];
        is.read(b);
        sdf = new String(b, "utf-8");
        sb.append(sdf);

        if (sdf.indexOf("\r\n\r\n") != -1) {
            headEnd++;
        }

        if (!firstRead) {
            Matcher matcher = CONTENT_LENGTH_PATTERN.matcher(sdf);
            if (matcher.find()) {
                acceptLenth = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1));
                firstRead = true;
                this.transferKind = TRANSFER_END_SPECIAL_LENGTH;
            } else {
                Matcher trunkMatcher = TRANSFER_ENCODING_PATTERN
                        .matcher(sdf);
                if (trunkMatcher.find()) {
                    String encode = trunkMatcher.group(1);
                    if ("chunked".equals(encode)) {
                        acceptLenth = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
                        this.transferKind = TRANSFER_END_TRANKED;
                        firstRead = true;
                    }

                }
            }
        }

    }
```

when I run the thread many times , about 2 hours later ,i cant get the result what i expect , so i have a dump of java stack as this :

```
"crawling_thread_socketwatchdog_0" #18 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0
tid=0x00007fb97c3da800 nid=0x605 runnable [0x00007fb965513000]   
java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketAvailable(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.available(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:490)
        - locked <0x00000000c55bd3d0> (a java.net.SocksSocketImpl)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.available(SocketInputStream.java:258)
        at net.health39.socketmonitor.monitor.AbstractHttpMonitor.testSocketConnectServer(AbstractHttpMonitor.java:67)
        at net.health39.socketmonitor.monitor.impl.HttpSocketDirectMonitor.startHttpConnect(HttpSocketDirectMonitor.java:23)
        at net.health39.crawlingprovider.WebWatchdogImplBySocketProvider.crawl(WebWatchdogImplBySocketProvider.java:141)
        at net.health39.crawlingengine.core.HttpProxyCrawlingProviderBase.crawl(HttpProxyCrawlingProviderBase.java:52)
        at net.health39.crawlingengine.core.CrawlingProviderBase.doCrawlingLoop(CrawlingProviderBase.java:189)
        at net.health39.crawlingengine.core.MultiThreadInitializer$CrawlingWorkerThread.run(MultiThreadInitializer.java:40)
```

i am very suprised ,it block ,and it keeps runing , from the info i guess it block in count = is .available ();
can someone help me ,(tips:i am chinese ,my english is not very standard,very sorry)

Comment: `available` does not block, but you are probably calling it endlessly in that loop condition. Are you sure the logic works properly? And why not just use a blocking read?

Comment: `while (is.available() == 0) {}` What is that supposed to do? Busy waiting? Why not just use a blocking read? That's exactly what it is made for.

Comment: The real question is why are you calling it? The initial `while (is.available() == 0) {}` loop is completely pointless. It is literally a waste of time. Remove it, and the other one, use a sensible buffer size, and just read.

Comment: The initial while (is.available() == 0) {} my purpose is to  wait the first package come, because the web transfer time , we cant first calls is.available() return what we want ,but through loops ,i cant wait inputStream has bytes to read

Comment: You *are* waiting, just in a pointless way that is smoking the CPU and giving rise to unfounded SO questions.

Answer (score -1):

> Why JDK says `InputStream.available()` can't block

You've misread that. What it actually says is

> returns an estimate of the number of bytes that can be read (or skipped over) from this input stream without blocking by the next invocation of a method for this input stream.

The operative words are 'that can be read ... without blocking'. It is the read that won't block.

But it's true anyway.

> it blocks

No it doesn't. You are calling it in a mindless spin loop. Remove both `available()` calls, use a sensible buffer size, and just read.